# ruby help - group generator (need to fix the last output ask for group and print only that group)

Tags: ruby

````
TASK   
 # Write a program that puts people into groups.  It should:
    # * Ask the user to enter the number of groups they want to create.
    # * Ask for people's names, one at a time, until the user enters `stop`.
    # * Grouping strategy
    #   * As an example, imagine there are three groups.
    #   * First person goes in the first group.
    #   * Second person goes in the second group.
    #   * Third person goes in the third group.
    #   * Fourth person goes in the first group.
    #   * Fifth person goes in the second group.
    #   * etc.
    # * Ask the user for the number of a group.
    # * Print the people in that group, each separated by a comma and a
    #   space.  Group numbers are "1-indexed".  This means that, if the
    #   user enters `1`, the first group should be printed, not the second
    #   group.
    # * Keep on asking the user for group numbers until the user enters
    #   `stop`.
    #
    # * Example output
    #   ```
    #   Enter number of groups
    #   3
    #   Enter a name
    #   Mary
    #   Enter a name
    #   Lauren
    #   Enter a name
    #   Awad
    #   Enter a name
    #   Govind
    #   Enter a name
    #   Isla
    #   Enter a name
    #   stop
    #   Enter the number of a group to print out
    #   1
    #   Mary, Govind
    #   Enter the number of a group to print out
    #   2
    #   Lauren, Isla
    #   Enter the number of a group to print out
    #   3
    #   Awad
    #   Enter the number of a group to print out
    #   stop
    #   ```
    #
    # * Note: You can assume the user will input an integer when asked how
    #   many groups they want to create.  You can assume the user will
    #   input integers for group numbers that exist when they are asked
    #   for the number of a group to print out.
````

CODE

```
    puts "Enter the number of groups you would like to create"
    group_number = gets.chomp.to_i

    array = Array.new(group_number) { [] }

    puts "Give me a name"
    count = 0
    while input_name = gets.chomp
      if input_name == "stop"
        puts "Type a group number"
        group_num = gets.chomp
        puts array[group_num]
        break
      else puts "Give me a name"
        array[count].push(input_name)
        count += 1
        count = 0 if count == group_number
      end
    end
```

ERRORS
...FFFFF.....

Failures:

1) Q2. People grouper has acceptable code quality
     Failure/Error: expect(code_quality.acceptable?).to(eq(true), code_quality.problems)

```
   Inspecting 1 file
   W

   Offenses:

   questions/question_2.rb:66:8: W: Lint/ElseLayout: Odd else layout detected. Did you mean to use elsif?
     else puts "Give me a name"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   questions/question_2.rb:67:5: C: Layout/IndentationConsistency: Inconsistent indentation detected.
       array[count].push(input_name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   questions/question_2.rb:68:5: C: Layout/IndentationConsistency: Inconsistent indentation detected.
       count += 1
       ^^^^^^^^^^
   questions/question_2.rb:69:5: C: Layout/IndentationConsistency: Inconsistent indentation detected.
       count = 0 if count == group_number
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   1 file inspected, 4 offenses detected

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -true
   +false
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) Q2. People grouper user asks to put 5 people into 1 group, prints the group outputs one group with all five people in it
     Failure/Error:
       expect { load "questions/question_2.rb" }
         .to output(/#{expected_output}/m).to_stdout

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # questions/question_2.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `load'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `block in set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

3) Q2. People grouper user asks to put 0 people into 1 group, and output 1 empty group outputs one empty group
     Failure/Error:
       expect { load "questions/question_2.rb" }
         .to output(/#{expected_output}/m).to_stdout

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # questions/question_2.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `load'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `block in set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

4) Q2. People grouper user asks to put 5 people into 3 groups, prints all 3 groups outputs three groups, two people first two, one person in third
     Failure/Error:
       expect { load "questions/question_2.rb" }
         .to output(/#{expected_output}/m).to_stdout

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # questions/question_2.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `load'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `block in set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

5) Q2. People grouper user asks to put 0 people into 3 groups, prints all 3 groups outputs three groups, all groups empty
     Failure/Error:
       expect { load "questions/question_2.rb" }
         .to output(/#{expected_output}/m).to_stdout

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # questions/question_2.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `load'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `block in set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:85:in `set_user_input_and_check_expected_output'
 # ./spec/question_2_spec.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Here are a couple of problems. `group_num = gets.chomp` makes `group_num` a string, but you cannot index an array with a string: `puts array[group_num]`. Nor can you write `puts array[group_num.to_i]` because the names for `group_num #=> "3"` are stored in `array["3".to_i-1] #=> array[2]`. Moreover if `group_num` equals `group_number` (terrible choice of names!), `arr[group_number.to_i]` will return `nil` because `array`'s last element is at index `group_number.to_i-1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Obtain the number of groups**

```
print "Enter the number of groups you would like to create: "
nbr_groups = gets.to_i
```

By using `print` rather than `puts` the string displayed does not end with a carriage return, so if the user enters, say, `'4'`, it will look like this:

```
Enter the number of groups you would like to create: 4
```

`nbr_groups` is arguably more descriptive than `group_number`.

If you are converting a string to an integer you don't have to `chomp`:

```
"312\n".to_i
  #=> 312
```

for that same reason that:

```
"254my, what a beautiful day it is today".to_i
  #=> 254
```

**Create an object to hold the results**

Here are some possibilities:

```
nbr_groups = 4 # (say)

arr1 = Array.new(nbr_groups) { [] }
  #=> [[], [], [], []] 
arr2 = Array.new(nbr_groups) { [] }.unshift('nil')
  #=> ["nil", [], [], [], []] 
h1 = (1..nbr_groups).each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n] = [] }
  #=> {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[]} 
h2 = ("1"..nbr_groups.to_s).each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n] = [] }
  #=> {"1"=>[], "2"=>[], "3"=>[], "4"=>[]}
```

Now suppose we want to add "Mary" to group "2". We would do that as follows:

```
grp = "2"
```

```
arr1[grp.to_i-1] << "Mary"
arr1 #=> [[], ["Mary"], [], []] 

arr2[grp.to_i] << "Mary" 
arr2 #=> ["nil", [], ["Mary"], [], []] 

h1[grp.to_i] << "Mary" 
h1 #=> {1=>[], 2=>["Mary"], 3=>[], 4=>[]}

h2[grp] << "Mary" 
h2 #=> {"1"=>[], "2"=>["Mary"], "3"=>[], "4"=>[]}
```

`arr2[0]` is never used. It's there just to avoid the `grp.to_i-1` adjustment needed with `arr1`. It's a bit hackish, but I'm hesitate to dismiss it because something like that can be found in the Ruby core: [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) contains the constant

```
Date::MONTHNAMES
  #=> [nil, "January", "February",..., "December"]
```

Lets suppose you use `arr1` (though I might use `h1`). To minimize the chance of confusing a 1-based group number with a zero-based array offset I will treat groups as zero-based and make the adjustment to group number when input is obtained and output is displayed.

**Set up your loop**

I suggest using [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), together with the keyword `break`, for all your loops unless you have good reason to use `while` or `until`. (Nobody uses `for`). Let me explain why.

Firstly, `loop` is very flexible. It can handle all types of loops. It also helps keep code away from prying eyes, a desirable coding objective. Suppose you have the code:

```
x = 1
loop do
  x = x + 1
  y = 2*x
  break if x == 3
end
x #=> 3
y #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object)
```

`loop` has a *block* that begins with `do` and ends with `end`. Since the variable `y` was created within the block it ceases to exist when the block ends. `x`, however, was created before the block, so it is still visible after the block.

By contrast if `y` were created in a `while` or `until` loop, it would be visible after the end of loop, because those loops are not blocks. This is an important advantage of using `loop`; the scope of local variables created in the block is confined to the block.

One more thing about the keyword `break`: if followed by an object, that object is returned from `loop`'s block. An example is given later on. Moreover, if

```
loop do
  ...
  break 7
  ...
end
```

is at the end of a method and `break 7` is executed, the method will return `7`.

Let's get the names and fill out `arr`.

```
grp = -1
loop do
  print "Gimme a name: "
  name = gets.chomp
  break if name.downcase == "stop"
  grp = (grp + 1) % nbr_groups
  arr[grp] << name
end
```

Suppose this were run when

```
nbr_groups #=> 3
```

and the entries were `"Ruth"`, `"Mary"`, `"Bob"`, `"Lou"`, `"Todd"`, `"Bif"` and `"Tim"`. We would then have:

```
arr #=> [["Ruth", "Lou", "Tim"], ["Mary", "Todd"], ["Bob", "Bif"]]
```

**Return information about a group**

Now we are to repeatedly ask for a (1-based) group number until "stop" is entered. For each group number given, we are to print the names of the persons in the group. I'll also add an example of error-checking.

```
loop do
  grp = loop do
    print "Gimme a group number: "
    grp = gets.chomp
    break grp if (1..nbr_groups).cover?(grp.to_i) ||
      grp.downcase == "stop"
    puts "That's not a valid group number. Try again."
  end
  break if grp.downcase == "stop"
  off = grp.to_i - 1
  puts "The members of group #{grp} are #{arr[off].join(', ')}"
end
```

If this is run and responses are `"1\n"`, `"99\n"`, `"cat\n"`, `"3\n"` and `"stop"`, the dialog would be as follows:

```
Gimme a group number: 1
The members of group 1 are Ruth, Lou, Tim
Gimme a group number: 99
That's not a valid group number. Try again.
Gimme a group number: cat
That's not a valid group number. Try again.
Gimme a group number: 3
The members of group 3 are Bob, Bif
Gimme a group number: stop
```